# Best way to republish android app

Tags: android, google-play, publish

after loosing an alias I see no other way than to reupload my app to playstore.
So what is the best strategy to that?

Is here anybody who has experience with this?

Because I find a lot "Lost my keystore" posts, this could be interesting for many people.

Comment: Remove the previous one and upload new one :)

Comment: U cant remove, only unpublish.

Comment: Yup then first unpublish and then re-publish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same situation as yours when I forgot the password of my keystore. What I did was to change my package name(optional) unpublish the previous application and then republish new one. The drawback of this is that your previous users are not able to see update of the application in play store.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the name of the app?

Comment: I copied all the details I had submitted from developer console then republished it with the same details

Comment: I have the same problem as I my Keystore was overwritten.So I am going to unpublish it and again re-publish with new keystore and old package name. Will this work?

Comment: @UVM i am certain that you will need to change your package name too. But its worth a shot.