# Republish an app instead of updating

Tags: android, google-play

My app has been in the playstore for a year now. 
Only 100 users downloaded it and due to that it's discoverability is very bad. 
I worked hard to improve it and completely rebuild it, including the icon the description and everything else. But unfortunately my app is suffering from it's past. 
Should I consider republishing my  app?
And if I should, how should I do that? Should I change the package name?

Comment: Republish the app and lose the bad ratings (along with the existing users). This is a very subjective trade-off decision. We can't answer it for you. Not to mention, this is not a programming question, it's not within the scope of StackOverflow. Please delete this question and find a more appropriate forum.

Answer (score 1):

[Follow this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121307/best-way-to-republish-android-app) However I'd say you need to advertise your app this time if you want more people to download it, otherwise it would face the same fate again.

Answer (score 0):

Re-plubishing your app with a new package name is not a good decision, at least in my opinion. I'm not sure if there are rules on the Play Store against it, but it won't appeal good to users, at least for those that will notice the difference.

If you have improved you app that much, people may start making better reviews.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the Unpublished existing application on Google play store and upload new APK with different package name